# How to set the TeX executables produced by MacTex 2018 to be the default ones?

Tags: texshop, mactex

I just installed MacTex 2018 but when I ran for instance `pdflatex main.tex` it does not call the executable produced by the MacTex just installed. Instead it calls an apparently old executable with the same name located at `/usr/local/bin/pdflatex` and the error `-bash: /usr/local/bin/pdflatex: Bad CPU type in executable` results. The `pdflatex` and other TeX-related executables produced by the new MacTex are located at `/Library/TeX/texbin/`. Now executing `echo $PATH` does show that the path of the old pdflatex is listed before the path of the new one thus the former is called. But how do I set the terminal so that all TeX-related command will be referred to the newly installed MacTex and delete all of the old TeX commands?. I checked the path to the old executable and there are multiple files whose name contains "tex" and I don't know whether all of these could just be `rm`-ed.

EDIT:
I obtained MacTex by downloading the full package from TUG website and run the installer. I did not install a separate front-end since MacTex already installs TexShop as it says in the website. Unfortunately I don't know where the old TeX comes from because it is an iMac in my laboratory that I am using but listing all "tex" containing files in the `/usr/local/bin/`, the resulting files dates range from 2004 to 2008. The macOS version is El Capitan 10.11.

Comment: Please tell us more about (a) which version of MacOS is installed on your system, (b) which front-end editor you use (TeXworks? TeXshop? something else?), and (c) how you installed MacTeX2018. E.g., did you download the full 3.2GByte version from http://tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html and run the installer program? If not, what did you do? Also, which older versions of MacTeX are on your system? FWIW, versions 2015, 2016, 2017, and 2018 are all installed on my system; after I installed version 2018 using the installer program, I experienced no problems of the variety you describe.

Comment: I edited the question to incorporate your question. By the way I am aware that older Mactex versions will have all its files isolated in `/usr/local/texlive/xxxx` but the existing versions in my mac are 2012, 2016, and 2018 whereas the executables described in my problem dated at most recent 2008.

Comment: I don't know where *really old* versions of MacTeX used to get installed or were supposed to be installed. I'm frankly surprised that versions 2008 and older would even run on your system. (I'm assuming that a reasonably up-to-date version of MacOS is installed on the iMac.) Anyway, it's probably a very good idea to blow away the executables from 2004 to 2008. TeX, LaTeX, and friends have all changed rather significantly since 2008...

Comment: My iMac runs on macOS 10.11, forget to mention that in the edits.
Well, that's part of my question actually. I am not sure whether it is really problem-free to just remove those old tex executables. As I said there are many of them in `/usr/local/bin/`, I am concerned whether removing them will cause any system-wide failure, at least on tex related processes.

Comment: I've edited your posting to add the 'texshop' tag and delete the 'pdftex' tag. Feel free to revert.

Comment: See [Where is PATH modified to include /usr/texbin?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/29744). I think this should solve your problem.  Also [Checking and removing multiple MacTex installations](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/177010) on removing older stuff.

Comment: As far as I remember, no TeX distribution for macOS (formerly Mac OS X) has ever installed executables in `/usr/local/bin`. The first real macOS distribution was maintained by Gerben Wierda, from 2000 to 2006; after that he quit and everybody switched to TeX Live. Fink and MacPorts don't install in `/usr/local/bin` either, by default. If you have older executables there, you should remove them.

Answer (score 0):

In your home directory, there will be a hidden file called `.bashrc`. Open this with your favourite text editor, and delete the location of the old TeX binaries from the path definition. Close the terminal and open a new one. You should now find that

```
which pdflatex
```

returns the location of the newer binary. Since the old distribution doesn't work, it's hard to see any downside to simply deleting it.

Comment: I am home now so I cannot open .bashrc file in my lab's iMac but I remember I also checked inside that file and the path to the old binaries was not defined there. The path to the old binaries are actually defined as the system-wide path, it is stored in the PATH environment variable. I cannot remove this path from PATH because there are other important binaries such as compilers in the same directory as the old tex binaries.

Comment: I only partially solved this issue by overriding using alias so that I define an alias `pdflatex` to the new pdflatex path in `.bash_profile`. Compilation from terminal such as `pdflatex main.tex` is now successful but the compilation from inside my emacs editor where I did most of my editing still fails because emacs still calls the path to the old binaries. I feel that the old binaries in some way need to be just removed so that any other program that uses its path will solely be redirected to the new one.

Comment: If you are using TeXShop rather than Terminal to compile your file check the `Path settings` section of the `Engine` tab of `TeXShop->Preferences`. The `(pdf)TeX` section should contain `/Library/TeX/texbin`.